# Send keys with modifiers in Capybara/Poltergeist

Tags: phantomjs, capybara, poltergeist

So Poltergeist `send_keys` let you do this:

```
element = find('input#id')
element.native.send_key('String')

element.native.send_keys('H', 'elo', :Left, 'l') # => 'Hello'
element.native.send_key(:Enter) # triggers Enter key
```

I'm looking to send key combinations like:

```
Control-A
Alt-C
```

Can't find any references or had any success with various attempts.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Issue #420](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist/issues/420) and the accompanying [commit](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist/commit/6de87ebbb0814de9b64f0115ccef1ca12b44c8d0), you can do it in the following way:

```
element.native.send_keys('H', [:Shift, 'elo'], :Left, 'l')
element.native.send_key([:Ctrl, :Enter])
```

You can define multiple modifiers like this:

```
[:Ctrl, :Shift, "aaa"]
```

There is currently no release containing that change (last one is 1.6.0), so you will need to build it yourself.

Comment: Thanks :) Thought this commit is in latest master release? Trying to pull in latest master in Gemfile via ``gem 'poltergeist', github: 'teampoltergeist/poltergeist', branch: "master"`` ... but still getting: ``Unfortunately PhantomJS behaviour for key modifiers is currently broken, we will add this in later versions`` (PhantomJS v 2.0.1-development)

Comment: Sorry, but I can't help you further. I'm not using poltergeist myself and I can't verify and tinker.

Comment: Whoops - sorry  --  @DanielMay  it appears to work fine with phantomjs v 2.0.0 on osx -- what platform are you running on?